# Cant check if a file exists in a directory

Tags: windows-10, python-3.6, pathlib

When i try to check if a file exists making use of the pathlib.Path method ".exists()" or "is_file()" what i get is False.

```
home = pathlib.Path.home()

path1 = home / r"Desktop\Python 3\Libro de Python3\my_directory\file1.txt"
path2 = home / r"Desktop\Python 3\file2.txt"
print(path1.exists())
print(path1.is_file())
print(path1.parent)

print("")

print(path2.exists())
print(path2.is_file())
print(path2.parent)
```

The output is:

```
False
False
C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Python 3\Libro de Python3\my_directory

True
True
C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Python 3
```

Why am i getting False for path1? is it because the path is too large?.

And yes, the file exists.

Comment: Can you share output of tree or dir command to verify if path is 100% correct.

Comment: Please check if this command will be successful from your cmd:


```notepad C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\Python 3\Libro de Python3\my_directory\file1.txt```

Comment: The command opens the file correctly and the program return True now...